# Derived Attribute/Property in Java?

Tags: java

I am new to Java - I am trying to understand how to use a "derived" "attribute" in a class. My understanding is that this is basically the same as the typical "full name" use case using a getter in C#, but I want to make sure. In C#, I would write.

```
    public string fullName 
    {
        get {return this.fName + " " + this.lName;}
    }
```

and then call it like this:

```
    Dude homieG = new Dude()
    {
      fName = "Homie",
      lName = "G"
    };

    Console.WriteLine(homieG.fullName);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ppd8j

How do I do this in Java? Googling "derived attribute (or 'property') java" gives me nothing.

Comment: Java doesn't have C#-like properties. Use methods instead.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method.  There are no "properties" in java.

```
public String getFullBlammy()
{
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks, I wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Comment: This code **explicitly** [defines a read-only property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) named `fullBlammy`.